UI not updating when using ListDetailPaneScaffold with custom composable on landscape mode
I'm using ListDetailPaneScaffold to display a list. When clicking on an element the detail view opens. In portrait mode this is working flawless. However, when testing on landscape mode I found that part of the UI wasn't updating when selecting different elements of the table. The problem seems to be a custom @Composable I wrote to underline certain parts of the text and make them clickable.
Here's the @Composable:
@Composable
    fun GetDiceFromText(text: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onClick: (String) -> Unit) {

        val colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme
        val textStyle = SpanStyle(color = colorScheme.onBackground)
        val primaryStyle = SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline, fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold, color = colorScheme.onBackground)
        val regex = Regex("\\d*d\\d+")

        val annotatedStringList = remember {

            var lastIndex = 0
            val annotatedStringList = mutableStateListOf<AnnotatedString.Range<String>>()

            for (match in regex.findAll(text)) {

                val start = match.range.first
                val end = match.range.last + 1
                val string = text.substring(start, end)

                if (start > lastIndex) {
                    annotatedStringList.add(
                        AnnotatedString.Range(
                            text.substring(lastIndex, start),
                            lastIndex,
                            start,
                            "text"
                        )
                    )
                }
                annotatedStringList.add(
                    AnnotatedString.Range(string, start, end, "dice")
                )
                lastIndex = end
            }

            if (lastIndex < text.length) {
                annotatedStringList.add(
                    AnnotatedString.Range(
                        text.substring(lastIndex, text.length),
                        lastIndex,
                        text.length,
                        "text"
                    )
                )
            }
            annotatedStringList
        }

        val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
            annotatedStringList.forEach {
                if (it.tag == "dice") {
                    pushStringAnnotation(tag = it.tag, annotation = it.item)
                    withStyle(style = primaryStyle) { append(it.item) }
                    pop()
                } else {
                    withStyle(style = textStyle) { append(it.item) }
                }
            }
        }

        ClickableText(
            text = annotatedString,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.plus(TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Justify)),
            modifier = modifier,
            onClick = { position ->
                val annotatedStringRange = annotatedStringList.first { (it.start..it.end).contains(position) }
                if (annotatedStringRange.tag == "dice") onClick(annotatedStringRange.item)
            }
        )
    }

And here's where I use GetDiceFromText
//Text(text = spell.text, Modifier.padding(16.dp))
GetDiceFromText(spell.text, Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
    scope.launch {
         snackBarHostState.showSnackbar(throwDiceFromText(it))
    }
}

The commented text is a regular Text composable that works and updates de UI just fine. I'll add a couple screenshots to illustrate my problem:

As you can see, the UI updates properly except for that text on the bottom.
I've tried changing the location of the GetDiceFromText composable, and tried finding alternate ways to achieve my goal, which is to underline all text matching the regex and making it clickable
